# ASP.NET forms authentication w/ http 2.0

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, http2

I'm experimenting with moving an existing enterprise app to HTTP 2.0 at my customer's request. The app uses ASP.NET Forms Authentication, and when accessed over HTTPS with HTTP 2.0-aware browser and server (Windows Server Tech Preview), authentication appears to succeed during the login action, redirecting to the requested URL, but then the server responds to the next request with a redirect back to the login URL again. After adding some diagnostic logging to Application_BeginRequest, I found that the auth cookie is present in the request, but an attempt to decrypt the ticket with FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() throws an exception stating that there are non-base-64 characters in the cookie. I suspect this has something to do with HTTP 2.0 header compression, but I would have thought that this should have been handled transparently by IIS and that the headers should have been decompressed by the time my code executes. Has anyone else experienced this and know of a workaround? Happy to provide additional information if I left anything out.

Comment: i believe that .net authentication is being revised again with the next releases, maybe there will be more information about this after it exits the preview stage (or further along in the preview stage)